# Can't work around .NET7 SQL Connection string encryption - The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, .net-7.0

I have upgraded an application from .NETCORE3.1 to .NET7. It is hosted on a Windows 2019 server with MSSQL.

When I ran into the common problem of the forced encryption on SQL encryption in development, adding  Trust server certificate=True or Encrypt=false solved the problem, however this solution is not working on the server.

I have added a certificate and set permissions but, I think due to the server not using a FQDN matching the subdomain I am working with (server has only a hostname) I then receive a different error - **The target principal name is incorrect** - even with **Trust server certificate=True** in the connection string.

The site and the database live on the same server, I'm not terribly concerned about whether their communication is encrypted or not.

I've tested with SSMS:

- Checking "Encrypt connection" only, gives me the principal name error
- Also checking "Trust server certificate" allows SSMS to connect successfully.

**Am I correct in my understanding that setting "Trust server certificate=true" or Encrypt=false in the connection string *should* allow the connection?
Anyone know what might be going wrong here?**

My connection string is currently:

```
"Data Source=STERP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CBooking;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=true"
```

I have tried various ways to write the trust part (with/without spaces, capitals etc) but no joy.
The same connection string worked fine before the update (but without the Trust Server Certificate=true part)

**Update**

After pulling in a server admin colleague who also cannot get this working, I've decided to downgrade from .NET7 to the last version prior to the forced encryption change and see if I can get that running.
Will revisit this particular issue again when Microsoft quits supporting that version! LOL.

Comment: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version 5 and later include a new [`HostNameInCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.hostnameincertificate) property. Have you tried setting that to match the Subject or one of the SubjectAltName (DnsName) values in the cert?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AlwaysLearning, I did not know about that property!
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be making any difference when set to match the Subject (altname is the same).

Comment: I guess a question worth asking: are you looking at SQL Server's certificate? It's not the same one that web services, such as IIS, might use. On the target server if you open SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager, go to "SQL Server Network Configuration" and right click on "Protocols for (Your Instance Name)" and choose Properties, you can find the certificate in-use by the instance on the Certificate tab.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I already had a certificate present for the IIS Site, which has been set in the config where you described and the SQL Service has been given permission to use it. Prior to that I was getting the "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that isn't trusted" message.
Are you saying this certificate isn't acceptable for use with SQL Server?

Comment: The service wouldn't start until permissions were given to use the cert, so once the service started I assumed that meant it accepted the certificate